# Are there large lockers in the Budapest-Déli station?

Tags: luggage-storage, train-stations, hungary, budapest

I have this picture, taken form [here](https://www.twoscotsabroad.com/budapest-to-ljubljana-the-most-efficient-route/):

[image: Budapest Lockers]

So I know there are lockers in there. The thing is that they don't seem big enough to hold large luggage (i.e. 70cm/27inches). Does anybody knows if perhaps the other side has larger ones?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [official page](https://www.mavcsoport.hu/mav-start/belfoldi-utazas/vasutallomas/budapest-deli) has this:

> Csomagmegőrző automaták az utascsarnokban, a nemzetközi pénztárhoz közeli bejárattól megközelítve balra találhatóak. Kisebb méretű automaták belső mérete: 350 mm X 500 mm X 750 mm Nagyobb méretű automaták belső mérete: 500 mm X 600 mm X 750 mm

> storage lockers are located in the passenger hall, to the left of the entrance close to the international ticket office. Internal dimensions of smaller machines: 350 mm X 500 mm X 750 mm Internal dimensions of larger machines: 500 mm X 600 mm X 750 mm

The [map](https://www.mavcsoport.hu/file/860675/download?token=ebVJgrI_) is bilingual. (surprise!)

I have [asked](https://www.reddit.com/r/budapest/comments/wokjlg/are_the_storage_lockers_at_d%C3%A9li_station/?) the local community whether the storage lockers are operational, I will update when we get an answer.

Comment: Ah I see! So they seem to be really deep right? I saw some large ones in Keleti like [here](https://themadtraveler.com/travel-tips/storing-luggage-at-budapest-keleti-train-station/) but they seem to have a different structure altogether.